# Using Interpolating Function

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I'm a bit of a noob with mathematica. I'm having a problem trying to use values from my solution. I've used ND solve to integrate ODEs. I have

```
sol = NDSolve[{
   u'[z] == uFunctionRhat,
   v'[z] == vFunctionRhat,
   w'[z] == wFunctionThat,
   y'[z] == yFunctionThat,
   uCond == 0,
   vCond == 0,
   wCond == 0,
   yCond == 1}, {u, v, w, y},
  {z, L, 0}]
```

where I can plot u,v,w,y easily.

My question is, HOW do I say find the value of u[z=0] ?

If I put u[0] it just returns the text. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `u[0] /. sol`

Comment: Perfect thank you!

Comment: Or `u[0] /. sol[[1]]` to remove the outer list between the `{` and `}` .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users) In particular [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18706).